# MergeSort without slicing list

Tags: python, algorithm

I am stuck on my algorithm, I am not sure why the output is not as expected. I want to design a merge sort algorithm without slicing the list. My idea is to use start and end index to simulate slicing the list. Can I get some help about the bug?
Thanks a lot!

```
def mergeSort(alist, start, end):
    print("Splitting ",alist[start:end])
    length = end - start
    if length >1:
        mid = length//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(alist, start, start + mid)
        mergeSort(alist, start + mid, end)


        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < mid and j < mid:
            if alist[start + i] <= alist[start + mid + j]:
                alist[k]=alist[start + i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=alist[start + mid + j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < mid:
            alist[k]=alist[start + i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < mid:
            alist[k]=alist[start + mid + j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging ",alist[start:end])
```

When I try:

```
alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist,0, len(alist))
```

I got

```
[44, 55, 77, 31, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
```

Comment: When you do `alist[k]=alist[start + i]` (for example), you are destroying whatever value was originally in `alist[k]`.  You should be swapping values rather than overwriting them.

Comment: There's no easy way to do a merge sort in place. While it's possible to do with some additional storage, you loose most of the performance benefits. It's important to realize that despite the name, Python `list` objects are not linked lists (which can be merge sorted easily and efficiently), they're dynamically resizable arrays.

Comment: Try to debug your code for this small failing example and compare it with what you would do by hand.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
You should post a specific bug; this is a "black box" posting: no attempt to trace or diagnose the problem.  You've also failed to document your intended algorithm; to "fix" the problem we first must reverse-engineer your intent from partially-obfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

1. First of all, the reference `alist[k]` does not make sense. It would make more sense if it were `alist[start + k]`, since you really don't want to change anything outside the window `start:end`.
2. But still then, you will be overwriting values in `alist` that you still need. Take for instance the first iteration of the first `while` loop (both `i` and `j` are zero). Assume that `alist[start + i] > alist[start + mid + j]`, so the `else` block kicks in. There you would do:

   ```
   alist[start + k] = alist[start + mid + j]
   ```

   Now realise that both `alist[start + k]` and `alist[start + i]` reference the same value, so this assignment destroyed the value that is needed in the next iteration of the `while` loop. It is for ever lost.

   You really need extra storage to manage this with lists.

   One way is to use a temporary list for gathering the merged values. You would not need the `k` index anymore, as you would just *append* values to this new list. Once it is populated, you can inject its values back into `alist`.
3. Finally, the `while` condition assumes that both halves to be merged have the same size, but this is not true. `end - start` could be odd, and then the second half has one more element. So doing `while i < mid and j < end` will miss one final iteration in that case.

   For this problem I would suggest to not use variables for *relative* sizes or *relative* offsets like your current `mid`, but to only use absolute offsets.

Here is the relevant code that deals with the above issues:

```
    mid = (start + end) // 2 # use absolute offsets only
    mergeSort(alist, start, mid)
    mergeSort(alist, mid, end)
    i = start # use absolute offsets only
    j = mid # use absolute offsets only
    merged = [] # temporary list
    while i < mid and j < end: # now condition is correct
        if alist[i] <= alist[j]:
            merged.append(alist[i]) # use append
            i = i + 1
        else:
            merged.append(alist[j])
            j = j + 1

    # add the remainder from the left side
    merged.extend(alist[i:mid])
    # inject back into main list
    alist[start:start+len(merged)] = merged
```